# Deleting an entire object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
arr = [
 {
   id:1
 },
 {
   id:2
 }
]
```

This is an example object structure. I want to delete first object in this array.

```
 delete arr[0];
```

Resulting structure is

```
[
{
  undefined * 1
},
{
  id:2
}
]
```

I have searched a lot and found that deleting an entire object will lead to dangling pointer problems. But i want resulting array to have only one object after deletion. Is there any other way to achieve this?

**EDIT**
   How to do if the object is neither first nor last?

Comment: `arr.splice(x, 1)` would be the generic solution.

Comment: Reason for downvoting pls. coz of duplicate? Which one is the duplicated copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, as an alternative to `Array.prototype.slice()`, use `array.prototype.shift()`, which simply removes the first element of the array:

```js
arr = [
 {
   id:1
 },
 {
   id:2
 }
];

console.log(arr); // [Object, Object]

arr.shift();

console.log(arr); // [Object]
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).
- [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a shorter array instead. To remove the first element, just slice the array:

```
arr = arr.slice(1);
```

When the previous array is discarded the first element will also be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to delete *anything* from an array is to resize it

```
arr = arr.slice(1)
```